# Why hunt replicants?

Tags: blade-runner

There’s been at least 4 or 5 years since I saw the movie so it may be there and I don’t remember. I don’t understand the whole purpose of hunting Replicants.

For the most part they seem to be hiding and living normal lives, not wanting to be found.

They seem to want to be left alone anyway.

They have an expiry date anyway so even if you don’t hunt them they’ll eventually die.

So what’s the point of the blade runners? Is it explained why replicants need to be hunt?

Comment: Why hunt other criminals?

Comment: "they seem to want to be left alone" contradicts Roy Batty not only actively seeking out Eldon Tyrell in order to ask for a longer live but also his reaction to Tyrell's answer (which I'm avoiding to spoil) which definitely attracts attention someone "wanting to be left alone" would avoid.

Comment: I wasn’t thinking about the main plot driver replicants.I remember at the beginning the was one replicant, moderately fat, I think in a yellow shirt getting tested. He looked to me as someone trying to stay off the radar with a mundane job.

Comment: Fish gotta swim, bird's gotta fly, Blade Runner's gotta persecute innocent replicants or possibly sleep with them.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I was gonna say "Because it's a laugh", but most of the hunters don't seem to especially enjoy their jobs.

Comment: @Valorum: they barely crack a smile!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Deckard doesn't seem to make any effort whatsoever to seduce Batty

Comment: @Valorum: when the chemistry's already so strong, just sit back and let it crackle innit.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Because they're basically amoral psychopaths, hence their incapacity to fool the VK test. Notably, many of them have killed humans to get to Earth and have killed on more than one occasion once they've arrived. If it was in the benefit of a replicant to kill you, it would do so without any compunction, in the same way that you might squash a bug that was annoying you, and with no more empathetic feeling.

In the original [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Androids_Dream_of_Electric_Sheep%3F), Rick describes them as "*solitary predators*" living among the human population.

> Evidently **the humanoid robot constituted a solitary predator**.
>
> Rick liked to think of them that way; it made his job palatable. In retiring—i.e., killing—an andy, he did not violate the rule of life laid down by Mercer. You shall kill only the killers, Mercer had told them the year empathy boxes first appeared on Earth. And in Mercerism, as it evolved into a full theology, the concept of The Killers had grown insidiously. In Mercerism, an absolute evil plucked at the threadbare cloak of the tottering, ascending old man, but it was never clear who or what this evil presence was. A Mercerite sensed evil without understanding it. Put another way, a Mercerite was free to locate the nebulous presence of The Killers wherever he saw fit. **For Rick Deckard an escaped humanoid robot, which had killed its master, which had been equipped with an intelligence greater than that of many human beings, which had no regard for animals, which possessed no ability to feel empathic joy for another life form’s success or grief at its defeat—that, for him, epitomized The Killers.**

Comment: Your quoted text makes it clear that replicants are _believed to be_ amoral psychopaths.  Whether they really are that is something PKDick very obviously distances himself from.  From the quoted text, that belief could just be an artifact of Deckard's opinion, or of the underlying theology in the society around him.

Comment: @SebTHU especially since the point of the book is that they strive for the same spiritual unity that humans achieve via their Ersatz-religion of Mercerism. Yearning to be an empathic being might suggest that you are pretty much capable of empathy to start with.

Comment: you guys read a different book. They pay a little lip service to the idea of spirituality, but they clearly do not even know what it is (as seen through their words and actions). They vote to decide whether Isadore should *not* be killed and he isn't simply because of his utility; Rachel throws a goat over the side of the building; it goes on. These are facts of the world, not Dekard's interpretations.

Comment: @Yorik, yes, it is quite possible to read a different book while looking at the same words. If you expect clear cut, senseless murder, you will certainly find it in the book, although I am puzzled that you read PKD when you expect something clear cut.

Comment: I was responding in part to the idea of Dick distancing himself: this I disagree with. But "the point of the book is that they [strive for spiritual unity]." That simply is untrue. "Expecting something clear cut" is just some weird projection on your part.

Comment: I think it's important to note that Mercerism turns out to be a complete (and deliberate) fraud, and that there is no real evidence after all that humans possess empathy and replicants don't.  Dick's perspective pretty overtly seems to be that the human claim to moral superiority over the replicants is absurd.  Rachel killed a goat; humans killed 99.999% of the animal life on Earth and had to build robots to replace it.  Replicants killed a handful of humans in their escape(s); humans fought multiple nuclear wars.

Comment: Do Androids dream of Electronic Sheep? Philip K Dick would say no. I studied this work in school, and the interpretation of Dick's intent was that machines would fundamentally lack the capacity for empathy, while humans possesses it to such a degree that in a sterile, uncaring world they needed to care for robotic animals to compensate. I don't think Dick whitewashed human evils; only that the robots were incapable of any of the good parts. The movies completely reversed the intent of the original story, but Philip Dick was a crazy guy and would probably not have minded.

Answer (score 8):

This question is answered fairly simply in the film.  Immediately after the opening credits, we read the following introductory text:

> Early in the 21st Century, THE TYRELL CORPORATION advanced robot evolution into the NEXUS phase - a being virtually identical to a human - known as a *Replicant*.
>
> The NEXUS 6 *Replicants* were superior in strength and agility, and at least equal in intelligence, to the genetic engineers who created them.
>
> *Replicants* were used Off-World as slave labor, in the hazardous exploration and colonization of other planets.
>
> After a bloody mutiny by a NEXUS 6 combat team in an Off-world colony, *Replicants* were declared illegal on earth - under penalty of death.
>
> Special police squads - BLADE RUNNER UNITS - had orders to shoot to kill, upon detection, any trespassing *Replicant*
>
> This was not called execution. 
> It was called retirement.

We don't have any more information on the exact reasons *Replicants* were declared illegal on Earth.  We might guess that it was either a retaliatory, [collective punishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_punishment), or perhaps a genuine safety precaution.

So, these orders and the law they were based on are the reason for the Blade Runners' actions, in general.

Later in the film, when asked about his feelings towards the Tyrell Corporation, Deckard explains his own, unemotional take on the situation:

> Replicants are like any other machine. They're either a benefit or a hazard. If they're a benefit, it's not my problem.

Apparently, if we're to take him at his word, Deckard feels that the Replicants he has retired were posing a hazard, rather than providing a benefit.

Comment: It's a wonderful line, and perhaps the best part is what it leaves out: a benefit or a hazard *to human beings.* The unspoken assertion is that those are the only benefits and hazards that matter.